# How can I kill a thread with python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a random number guessing game with GUI (Tkinter) and this comes up `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`. I'm trying to kill the thread but I can't find any way. Here's the code:

```py
def main(c):
    global max_num, number, guess_num, enter, l1, t1

    if c <= 5:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Import error', message='Please add a bigger number than 5')
        max_num.delete(0, END)
    else:
        number = random.randrange(1, c+1)
        print(number)

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: process(int(guess_num.get())))
        l1 = Label(root, text='Whats the number?')
        guess_num = Entry(root, bd=3)
        enter = Button(root, text='Enter', command=t1.start)

        l1.grid(row=2)
        guess_num.grid(row=3)
        enter.grid(row=3, column=1)

def process(answer):
        global number

        if number == answer:
            result = Label(root, text='Correct Answer!')

            result.grid(row=4)
            guess_num.destroy()
            enter.destroy()
            l1.destroy()

        else:
            if answer > number:
                wrong_result = Label(root, text='Wrong Answer! Your answer is bigger than the random number', fg='red')

            elif answer < number:
                wrong_result = Label(root, text='Wrong Answer! Your answer is smaller than the random number', fg='red')

            wrong_result.grid(row=4)
            time.sleep(3)
            wrong_result.destroy()
```

In the first function (`main`) is where I call the Thread and in the second function (`process`) is where I want to kill the `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you that passing `command=t1.start` will result in calling `start()` on the *same* `t1` instance every time the button is pressed. In Python, you cannot call `thread.start()` multiple times on the same thread instance. Change the following lines:

```
        ...
        print(number)

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: process(int(guess_num.get())))
        l1 = Label(root, text='Whats the number?')
        guess_num = Entry(root, bd=3)
        enter = Button(root, text='Enter', command=t1.start)
        ...
```

To

```
        ...
        print(number)

        def process_in_thread():
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: process(int(guess_num.get())))
            t1.start()

        l1 = Label(root, text='Whats the number?')
        guess_num = Entry(root, bd=3)
        enter = Button(root, text='Enter', command=process_in_thread)
        ...
```